# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Want to consult on the below error message:

Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

These are the possible causes:

1. There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.
2. A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
3. The application may not be properly configured. Please check whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any incorrect configurations, and restart this application.
4. A service that the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that service.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's 
log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)
Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
Application root:
/usr/local/sipfish/webui
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb  44  in `connect'
1   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb  44  in `initialize'
2   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb 17  in `new'
3   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb 17  in `mysql2_connection'
4   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   304 in `new_connection'
5   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   323 in `checkout_new_connection'
6   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   265 in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
7   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   261 in `loop'
8   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   261 in `block in checkout'
9   /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb    211 in `mon_synchronize'
10  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   260 in `checkout'
11  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   162 in `connection'
12  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   409 in `retrieve_connection'
13  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb  115 in `retrieve_connection'
14  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb  89  in `connection'
15  /usr/local/sipfish/webui/config/initializers/verify_voip_phone_parity.rb    1   in `'
16  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 234 in `load'
17  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 234 in `block in load'
18  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 225 in `load_dependency'
19  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 234 in `load'
20  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/engine.rb 556 in `block (2 levels) in '
21  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/engine.rb 555 in `each'
22  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/engine.rb 555 in `block in '
23  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `instance_exec'
24  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `run'
25  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  55  in `block in run_initializers'
26  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `each'
27  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `run_initializers'
28  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/application.rb    96  in `initialize!'
29  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb   30  in `method_missing'
30  /usr/local/sipfish/webui/config/environment.rb  5   in `'
31  config.ru   3   in `require'
32  config.ru   3   in `block in
'
33  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb 51  in `instance_eval'
34  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/builder.rb 51  in `initialize'
35  config.ru   1   in `new'
36  config.ru   1   in `
'
37  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225 in `eval'
38  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225 in `load_rack_app'
39  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  157 in `block in initialize_server'
40  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 572 in `report_app_init_status'
41  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  154 in `initialize_server'
42  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204 in `start_synchronously'
43  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180 in `start'
44  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  129 in `start'
45  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 253 in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
46  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132 in `lookup_or_add'
47  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 246 in `block in spawn_rack_application'
48  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in `block in synchronize'
49      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
50  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in `synchronize'
51  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 244 in `spawn_rack_application'
52  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 137 in `spawn_application'
53  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 275 in `handle_spawn_application'
54  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in `server_main_loop'
55  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206 in `start_synchronously'
56  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11//helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 99  in `
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Your database password for root and the root password in config/database.yml do to match.

You need to check the following entry in your database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: some_password
```

or a corresponding entry for the environment you are trying to connect to.